# db migration in orientdb - nodejs- orientjs

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientjs

I am creating a migration script using

```
orients migrate create something
```

The up function looks like this

```
 db.class.create('User', 'V')
    .then(function (User) {
        console.log("Created class User");
    })
```

}

The 'then' function is not getting executed. But the class is getting created. Is there anything missing?

I am using 
orientjs version: 2.1.0
orientdb version 2.1.6 community edition

----UPDATE-----
Here is the github issue : https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/issues/120

Answer (score 0):

You must return something in the up function in order to see .then output.